# How do you assign a code to a file to recover it later?

Tags: android, git

This application is just a concept. I am plan to develop it soon.
This application will record chess moves from input of the user.
The app will then save the chess moves as a txt file.
Now comes the tricky part.
The app will assign the txt file a code.
Then by inputting this code into an application on a computer the txt file will be downloaded onto the computer.
Recording the chess moves is fine; how would I assign the txt file its code and recover it from a computer?

**UPDATE:** After thinking about this for a while longer I think it would be best to upload this txt file to GitHub and having a shell script clone it onto a pc. The problem is I can't find any guides on how to do that.

Comment: Unlike with previous portable devices, Android does not really have any "sync" mechanism which works by connecting a device directly to an end-user's PC.  There are possibilities using SDK components or local networking, but these require configuration changes average users may be hesitant or unwilling to make.  Therefore the best solutions tend to be those which use a remove server visible to both the device and the PC which facilitates the transfer.

Comment: This would typically be stored in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using git for the purpose of your application is like trying to hammer a nail with a rake.

To better answer your question you may want to use a hashing algorithm and key value store to create a "repository" for your files. The hashing algorithm will create unique identifiers and the key/value store would provide an establish way of retrieving a value, your text file, based on a key, it's hash.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know about hashing at all.

Answer (score 0):

there should be no way to extract the "txt" file youre talking about unless you store it in external storage and export it manually or upload the file to a webresource.